# unity admob + firebase remote config issue : admob mediation error

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-remote-config, firebase-admob

I have implemented admob and firebase (analytics, messaging, firestore) in unity all are working well. Later I added a remote config of firebase and even it's working well. But now when I request any ads like banner, rewarded, it's throws error :

**E/Unity: AndroidJavaException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.gms.ads.mediation.admob.AdMobExtras**

I have removed remote config sdk from unity but still is throws error. I would be thankful if anyone can help me out.

**VERSION USED**

**Unity 2021.2.13f1** | **Admob v7.0.0** | **Firebase 8.10.0**

[ERROR PHOTO](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pxQCA.png)

Answer (score 1):

I Solved this by changing this line into GoogleMobileAdsDependencies.xml

```
<androidPackage spec="com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:20.6.0">
```

to this line

```
<androidPackage spec="com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:[20.6.0]">
```